# Equivalent of "illegal" for violating civil law

Tags: civil-law, legal-terms

If "illegal" is typically used for criminal law, what adjective or adjectives are generally used for breaking civil law?

Comment: As the accurate answers given indicate, the premise of your question is incorrect, although it is a common misconception.

Comment: Possibly [tortious](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tortious).

Comment: Perhaps "uncivil"? :-)

Comment: @TimLymington Committing an offence is possibly "offensive".

Comment: @ohwilleke: I was basing this on Google's definition of "contrary to or forbidden by law, especially criminal law." (at https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define%3Aillegal ) and did note I was speaking of "typically", but if it is regularly used, I stand corrected. I was also thrown by https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373704/use-of-the-term-illegal-to-describe-a-person/373705#373705 and in any case interested in alternatives which were civil only.

Comment: @CJDennis Nope. Offensive means contrary to standards of propriety and could be civil, criminal or not illegal but contrary to informal cultural norms.

Comment: Helpful, @TimLymington, but are there no adjectives which would refer to breaking civil law only (including non-tort civil law), such as an alternative for "illegal immigrant" which avoided the ambiguity of suggesting a violation of criminal law?

Comment: @Brett: in the sense in which it is opposed to criminal, civil law protects only the rights of other people. Those who break government regulations (including illegal immigrants) are criminals.

Comment: Ok, but for those who enter legally but overstay a visa or those who enter illegally but evade capture until the statute of limitations expires, these are not subject to conviction under a criminal statute (even though they may be deported).

Comment: Please don't try to have a conversation in comments: this site is for questions and answers only. The actions you refer to are 'illegal' because they break the criminal law. If you have a question about whether they remain illegal after the statute of limitations expires you should ask that separately, with a link to this question (though the answer's probably yes).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The term "illegal" is also often used for actions that the law prohibits, but that give rise to civil liability, rather than criminal prosecution. We see such use a lot in questions on Law.SE.  One also says that a person "is liable" when there are grounds for a civil suit against that person. One might also say that such a person "has commited a tort" or "has civil liability" or "could be held liable". In the specific cases of copyright, trademark, and patent law, one says that a violator "his infringed" or has committed infringement" and that an act contrary to those laws "is an infringement".

Comment: Another word for many, but not all, non-criminal wrongs is "actionable."

Answer (score 25):

### “Illegal” is not limited to criminal matters

Illegal and unlawful are synonymous and refer to any conduct which is in breach of any law. So:

- Murder is illegal and a crime
- Stopping in a No Stopping zone is illegal and a civil offence
- Breaking a contract is illegal and exposes the breacher to civil damages

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Re: illegal and unlawful, it may be helpful to point out that, (yes, as with other synonyms), there may be slight differences. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14436/what-is-the-difference-between-illegal-and-unlawful/14454#14454 including its excerpt from the Oxford English Dictionary. (However, I think we also do use "illegal" for an act that "merely contravenes the rules that apply in a particular context" such as "an illegal serve".)

Comment: I have rarely if ever heard legal professionals refer to breach of contract as "illegal", at least not in ordinary US commercial law. What is the law that you see being broken?

Comment: @Hasse1987 Contract law - the one that obliges you to fulfill your contracts.

Comment: @DaleM A common view is it doesn't oblige you, it allows you to choose between fulfilling it and paying some money. You can try to analogize this to the criminal law, but I don't believe that agrees with common usage. Are you arguing from a dictionary definition? If so you should state so in your answer.

Comment: @Hasse1987 that might be a common view in a figurative sense but a contract is *literally a declaration of obligations* of the respective parties. It seems very strange to argue that the language of legal obligation is categorically inappropriate where a party *voluntarily takes on a new legal obligation and discloses his undertaking to be bound by this obligation*.

Comment: Yup. As further evidence, "illegal contracts" aren't just ones that involve criminal actions. Civil wrongs, acts against public policy etc etc all make a contract illegal.

Comment: Not the best of examples, these.  Stopping in a no-stopping zone is a criminal offence in some jurisdictions.

Comment: @JdeBP Presumably the reader can apply the tiniest amount of imagination to consider a jurisdiction where it's not, and still get the same amount out of this answer.

Comment: @Will We're talking in circles. You can make an argument that the term "should" be used to apply to breach of contract, based on some dictionary definition of "illegal". But surely you can understand that argument may have nothing to do with the reality of the term's usage?

Comment: @NathanCooper That's not evidence, since "illegal contracts", e.g., public policy violations, are not breaches of contract.

Comment: @DaleM in some jurisdictions Stopping in a No Stopping zone is a criminal offense; i.e. class C misdemeanor in Texas.

Comment: @Hasse1987 I'm not making any normative statement at all. The question is about how to refer to a civil wrong to reflect specifically that it is unlawful to commit it. That doesn't mean that the term should feature routinely in the legal lexicon - as you have successfully argued it doesn't - because of course professionals tend not to need to labor the point that they're illegal.

Comment: @Will You're not making a normative statement, but the op is asking for one, "what adjective or adjectives are generally used" ...

Comment: @Hasse1987 I suppose then you could advocate for the answer "adjectives are not generally used for breaking civil law" because it's not a useful distinction in "general" usage. But I don't find that especially helpful.

Answer (score 4):

[Tortious](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Tortious) might be an adjective you could use. The word essentially means a civil violation (although in a strict legal definition, I believe there also need to be some kind of proveable damages).

I usually only see it in the phrase "[tortious interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortious_interference)", but I suspect a legal audience at least would understand its meaning alone.

Comment: I have seen this used in "Tortious conduct". Strictly speaking, it does not apply to a civil wrong that is not a tort. Interestingly (at least to me), the root is the same as "torture", The wrong was metaphorically an inflection of pain.

Answer (score 4):

In the comments to the question, the OP talks about immigration law. US immigration law uses the terms **lawful and unlawful** to encompass both criminal, civil, and regulatory aspects of immigration law.

This includes immigration violations where there isn't an intent to immigrate. For example, somebody can be "unlawfully present" when they overstay their visa by accident. If you called it "illegal immigrant", you can imply an intent to immigrate.

Similarly, if you hold a green card, you're a "[lawful permanent resident](https://www.dhs.gov/immigration-statistics/lawful-permanent-residents)".

Comment: Under the definition of *immigrant* at 8 USC 1101(a)(15), anyone who isn't a US citizen or national or a member of one of the enumerated nonimmigrant classes is an immigrant, regardless of intent (except inasmuch as intent is relevant to determining membership in some of those classes). So someone whose nonimmigrant status lapses is indeed an immigrant for the purpose of the INA.

Comment: @phoog I don't follow. Somebody comes in legitimately on a B-1 visa which according to (15)(B) makes them a nonimmigrant alien. They screw up their flights and stay one day over. By what regulation do they become an "immigrant"? Where does it say that the intent of returning home, in (15)(B),no longer matters?

Comment: There's no regulation that says that explicitly, because the regulations are more concerned with the fact that the person you describe becomes deportable, and the law surrounding deportable aliens does not generally distinguish between immigrants and nonimmigrants.  But [8 CFR 214.1(a)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.1#a_3) notes that overstaying may constitute a failure to maintain status ("may" perhaps gives some discretion) and by [8 USC 1101(a)(15)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_15), any alien without valid nonimmigrant status is an immigrant.

Comment: The discretion implied by "may" perhaps saves your business visitor who messed up the flights.  But maybe not.  It's not a good idea to plan to stay exactly six months on a visitor visa.

Comment: @phoog You're missing the point of my answer completely. The point is you need a general term to refer to somebody who's not supposed to be in the country regardless of immigrant intent and that's "unlawfully present". I don't see anything in your links that says an unintentionally overstaying a business visa is somehow better described as an "illegal immigrant". All I see is some definitions and unimportant facts about deportation.

Comment: No, unlawfully present is a poor choice because it is a term of art under [8 USC 1182(a)(9)(B)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_9_B), which excludes minors, among others.  It is also an adjective phrase rather than a noun phrase. "Unauthorized" is perhaps the most descriptive term that isn't specifically defined by statute, and "unauthorized immigrant" is just as applicable as "unauthorized alien."